# Plotting Trigonometric functions in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and I need help plotting trigonometric functions. To be specific the x-limits involved. I have the following code.

```
coz<-function(x) {cos(x)}
plot(coz, 0, 2*pi, bty = "n", lty = 3, pos = 0)
```

This yields a curve with the x-axis values running from 0 to 6. I would love it if the x-axis was labeled  *0, pi/2, pi, 3pi/2* and *2pi* just like a normal trig curve. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the default labels with `xaxt="m"` and then use the `axis()` function to draw whatever labels you like. For example

```
coz <- function(x) {cos(x)}
plot(coz, 0 , 2*pi, bty="n", lty=3, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=c(0,pi/2,pi,3*pi/2, 2*pi), 
     labels=expression(0,pi/2,pi,3*pi/2, 2*pi))
```

[image]